# Typescript primitive types: any difference between the types "number" and "Number" (is TSC case-insensitive)?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I meant to write a parameter of type `number`, but I misspelled the type, writing `Number` instead.

On my IDE (JetBrains WebStorm) the type `Number` is written with the same color that is used for the primitive type `number`, while if I write a name of a class (known or unknown) it uses a different color, so I guess that somehow it recognizes the misspelled type as a correct/almost-correct/sort-of-correct type.

When I compile the code, instead of complaining for example that the compiler couldn't found a class named `Number`, TSC writes this error message:

```
Illegal property access
```

Does that mean that `number` and `Number` both co-exists as different types?

If this is true, which is the difference between those classes?

If this is not the case, then why it simply didn't write the same error message it displays for unknown classes ("The name 'Number' does not exist in the current scope")

This is the code:

```
class Test
{
    private myArray:string[] = ["Jack", "Jill", "John", "Joe", "Jeff"];

    // THIS WORKS
    public getValue(index:number):string
    {
        return this.myArray[index];
    }

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK: ILLEGAL PROPERTY ACCESS
    public getAnotherValue(index:Number):string
    {
        return this.myArray[index]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

JavaScript has the notion of *primitive* types (number, string, etc) and *object* types (Number, String, etc, which are manifest at runtime). TypeScript types `number` and `Number` refer to them, respectively. JavaScript will usually coerce an object type to its primitive equivalent, or vice versa:

```
var x = new Number(34);
> undefined
x
> Number {}
x + 1
> 35
```

The TypeScript type system rules deal with this (spec section 3.7) like this:

> For purposes of determining subtype, supertype, and assignment
>   compatibility relationships, the Number, Boolean, and String primitive
>   types are treated as object types with the same properties as the
>   ‘Number’, ‘Boolean’, and ‘String’ interfaces respectively.

Comment: One might add that they are not exactly cross assignable: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20x%3Anumber%3B%0Avar%20y%3ANumber%3B%0Ay%20%3D%20x%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%20%0Ax%20%3D%20y%3B%20%2F%2F%20not%20okay%20

Comment: Also to answer the original poster : Yes TSC (like javascript) is case  sensitive :)

Answer (score 196):

To augment Ryan's answer with guidance from the [TypeScript Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html):

> *Don't* ever use the types `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Symbol`, or `Object` These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are
>   almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.
>
> ```
> /* WRONG */
> function reverse(s: String): String;
> ```
>
> *Do* use the types `number`, `string`, `boolean`, and `symbol`.
>
> ```
> /* OK */
> function reverse(s: string): string;
> ```

Comment: But typescript documentation says Object. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @atilkan That's fun. I guess they aren't taking their own advice.

Comment: That documentation was written before lower-case `object` was a thing

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Guess we should report this.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin What about array, i can't find any lowercase example.

Comment: @atilkan You should probably be using `[]` to denote array types. There might be exceptions though, I'm not sure.

Comment: @VictorZamanian There is a good explanation here -> https://toddmotto.com/typing-arrays-typescript

Comment: If you do this: `console.log(number);`, the typescript compiler will warn you "number only refers to a type, ...", but `console.log(Number);` is fine.

Comment: @KuanYuChu this happens if you have no `number` identifier in scope. If you declare `let number = 1` then the warning disappears, since `number` now refers to that variable. You would get the same behaviour if you declare `interface MyInterface` and try to do `console.log(MyInterface)` - a warning that it's a type, not a concrete thing that exists. However, `Number` is a function that always exists in JS, so it's always in scope.

Comment: This is such an easy mistake to make. Do you know of any eslint rules, ts configs, or similar that help prevent devs from making this mistake?

Comment: Found https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md in case anyone's interested :)

Comment: But in Vue.js, variables are declared with these capitalized types, like in `prop` variable is declared like `message: String`

Answer (score 3):

As the TypeScript doc says:

```
var Number: NumberConstructor
(value?: any) => number
```

> An object that represents a number of any kind. All JavaScript numbers
>   are 64-bit floating-point numbers.

As it says, take `any` as parameter and return number or `null`

It give an easy way to check a value is number or not

```
Number("1234");   // 1234
Number("1234.54") // 1234.54
Number("-1234.54") // -1234.54
Number("1234.54.33") // null
Number("any-non-numeric") // null
```

So simply we can use to check the number, like:

```
if(Number(val)){
   console.log('val is a number');
} else {
   console.log('Not a number');
}
```