# Does it matter whether Number or number is used in Typescript / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does it matter whether Number or number is used in Typescript / Javascript?  For example does number perform better than Number?  I'm also assuming that Javascript will be fine with number / Number and vice versa?

The answer in [Typescript primitive types: any difference between the types “number” and “Number” (is TSC case-insensitive)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487220/typescript-primitive-types-any-difference-between-the-types-number-and-numbe) says never use `Number`, but does not explain why.  In other words it does not say, "If you use Number then this will happen ..." or "If you use Number vs number then `typeof` or `instanceof` checks outcomes will be different depending on what type is used".

For example if you use `const arr = any[]` and then pass a `Number` instance as an index to the array Javascript throws an exception.  I'm not saying this is the case, just providing an example of the type of answer I'm looking for.

### Update

Just came across a specific example from my code:

> `const errorIndex:Array<Number> = [];`

Does it matter whether `Array<Number>` or `Array<number>` is used?

Comment: I already looked at that answer.  Is says never use Number ... but does not really explain why?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. An example of the usage you're asking about would help a **lot**. Are you talking about type annotations? Actual use? Both? Something else?

Comment: Well I'm right in the middle of writing this: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator and I think I have used number in some places and Number in some others ... so now I'm wondering whether it need to do all Number or number ...So does there exist a single case where it matters whether something is a number or Number instance?

Comment: Does there exist a single case where it matters mathematically or perhaps for array indexes whether we are using a Number or number instance?

Comment: Neither of those, no, because in both cases Number instances will be coerced to their equivalent primative. But Numbers (capital N) are objects. Unless you have a reason for using their object-ness (storing additional properties on them, etc., which would be Very Odd Indeed), there's no reason to use Numbers rather than numbers. The closest thing to a use case I can think of is that you could use `null` to indicate "no number," but there's already the primitive number value `NaN` ("not a number"), so you don't even need that.

Comment: Cool - I just now realized that Typescript supports both number and Number ... and freaked a little ... Hopefully nothing blows up then :)

Comment: @TJCrowder you still marked it as a duplicate after I explained in great detail why it is not ...???

Comment: @ Ole - **I** voted "unclear." Unfortunately, SO's closure messages are misleading. People have been complaining about it for years, but SE does nothing about it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269073/dont-say-i-marked-something-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt

Comment: Ah - OK - thanks for explaining.  I think SO is trying, but they have a little ways to go :)