# Why does Typescript have Capitalized and lowercase types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I notice that types in visual studio code such as `string` and `String` as well as `number` and `Number` exist in capitalized and lowercase form. I also noticed that when calling native javascript methods and properties the difference matters.

What is the point of this and which should I be using by default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487220/typescript-primitive-types-any-difference-between-the-types-number-and-numbe

Comment: Thanks! That does answer my question--asked in a very different way.