# Typescript: Type 'Number' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

In TypeScript, I have an array that I am using like a map to access another array of objects. Here is an extremely simplified example of my code:

```
var mp : Number[] = [1, 2, 0];
var arr : any[] = ['a', 4, /regex/];

console.log(arr[mp[2]])
```

However, running this yields:

```
error TS2538: Type 'Number' cannot be used as an index type.
```

I've looked elsewhere but the other answers for this type of error don't pertain to something as simple as an array and a `Number`. If not a `Number` object, how can I index an array?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

TypeScript has two basic number types, the primite `number` and the Object type `Number`. Refer to [TypeScript: Difference between primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487220/typescript-primitive-types-any-difference-between-the-types-number-and-numbe) for an explanation, but in short:

> JavaScript has the notion of primitive types (number, string, etc) and object types (Number, String, etc, which are manifest at runtime). TypeScript types number and Number refer to them, respectively.

In fact, if you run:

```
console.log(typeof 1);
```

You will notice that it returns `number`, not `Number`.

If you change your map to be an array of `number` objects, your code will compile without errors.

Comment: `typeof(1)` is not necessary, just `typeof 1` is most commonly used. It's unnecessary parentheses making it look like a function call, just like typing
 `return(1)`

Comment: Thanks, removed the parantheses

Comment: "*TypeScript has two number types, the primite number and the Object type Number.*" there is also [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: changed to "basic number types"